# The [multiple-systems] tag has been burninated

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I've just burninated [multiple-systems](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-systems). I'm leaving this post for record-keeping.

It had the following tag wiki excerpt (and no full tag wiki):

> For questions that involve multiple rules systems at once, or interactions between them.

It was on these questions, almost all of which now have the [conversion](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conversion) tag:

- [How can I stat up a troll in 5 different systems?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/11552/how-can-i-stat-up-a-troll-in-5-different-systems) [closed]
- [Applying Paranoia techniques to D&D 5e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/113371/applying-paranoia-techniques-to-dd-5e)
- [Travel between D&D editions or gaming systems](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/112562/travel-between-dd-editions-or-gaming-systems) [closed]
- [Hit Points replacements](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/108507/hit-points-replacements) [closed]
- [Running a dungeoncrawl with several game systems at once](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/14605/running-a-dungeoncrawl-with-several-game-systems-at-once)
- [What system produces characters that are easiest to convert to another system?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/19506/what-system-produces-characters-that-are-easiest-to-convert-to-another-system) [closed]

Compared to other game/edition-bridging tags like [conversion](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conversion) or [edition-comparison](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/edition-comparison) which say *in what way* the multiple systems relate, this tag didn't say anything other than “there is more than one system here” ... but we'd already be able to tell that from seeing those game systems' tags *right beside this one*. Ironically its presence using up 1 of the 5 allowed tags would also only make fitting those other game systems' tags in more difficult.

It is also woefully underused compared to our body of questions *actually about* multiple systems. Evidently it did not catch on as useful to tag questions about multiple systems with [multiple-systems](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-systems).

The only legitimate usage of this tag left looked like [Running a dungeoncrawl with several game systems at once](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/14605/1204), but I didn't feel that merited hosting a tag that was otherwise flawed & underused for its explicit purpose.